# Minimizing surface area of a fixed volume pyramid

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

I assume you're familiar with the classic "find the dimensions of an <X> containing 1 liter with minimum surface area". I remember solving this in school at least for a <cylinder> and a <square prism> and found the rule "make square cross sections and it becomes minimal surface area" to be satisfying but kind of boring.

Now that I'm teaching the stuff myself, I took up the challenge to solve for the cases of <cone> and <rectangular pyramid> as they don't usually have square (orthogonal) cross sections – and I got myself stuck on the pyramid. This is how I started:

- rectangular base area: $B = 2a \cdot 2b$ (note that I defined $a$ and $b$ as half of the respective base dimensions)
- pyramid height: $h$
- slanted heights: $h_a = \sqrt{b^2 + h^2}$, $h_b = \sqrt{a^2 + h^2}$
- slanted areas: $S = 2 \cdot (a \cdot h_a + b \cdot h_b)$
- let the unit be `1 cm`, so volume $V = \frac{1}{3} \cdot B \cdot h = 1000$
- surface area $A = B + S = 4ab + 2 \cdot (a \cdot h_a + b \cdot h_b)$

I then defined $r := \frac{b}{a} \Rightarrow b = ra$ and $k := \frac{750}{r}$, so:

- $V = \frac{1}{3} \cdot 4ra^2 \cdot h = 1000 \iff h = \frac{750}{ra^2} = ka^{-2}$
- $\Rightarrow h' = -2 \cdot ka^{-3}$; $h^2 = k^2a^{-4}$, $(h^2)' = -4 \cdot k^2a^{-5}$
- $h_a = \sqrt{r^2a^2 + h^2}$, $h_b = \sqrt{a^2 + h^2}$

So I'm pretty sure I arrived at a correct representation of the surface area:

$$A(a) = 4ra^2 + 2a \cdot \left( \sqrt{r^2a^2 + h^2} + r \cdot \sqrt{a^2 + h^2} \right)$$

$$A'(a) = 8ra + 2 \cdot \left( \sqrt{r^2a^2 + h^2} + r \cdot \sqrt{a^2 + h^2} \right) + 2a \cdot \left( \frac{2r^2a + (h^2)'}{2\sqrt{r^2a^2 + h^2}} + r \cdot \frac{2a + (h^2)'}{2\sqrt{a^2 + h^2}} \right) \stackrel{!}{=} 0$$

$$4ra + \sqrt{r^2a^2 + h^2} + r \cdot \sqrt{a^2 + h^2} + \frac{2r^2a^2 + a(h^2)'}{2\sqrt{r^2a^2 + h^2}} + r \cdot \frac{2a^2 + a(h^2)'}{2\sqrt{a^2 + h^2}} = 0$$

$$\dots$$

A few lines later, I derived this:

$$ 4ra^3 + \frac{2r^2a^6 - k^2}{\sqrt{r^2a^6 + k^2}} + r \cdot \frac{2a^6 - k^2}{\sqrt{a^6 + k^2}}= 0 \text{, with constants } r, k \in \mathbb{R}^{\gt 0}$$

And frankly, the only step forward I can see is to choose a concrete value for the "aspect ratio" $r$ and continue with a fixed shape that way.

Is there anything else I could do to solve this monstrosity for $a$?

~LDer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is made a little easier with Lagrange multipliers[1]. One maximises

$$L(a,b,h,\lambda)=A(a,b,h)-\lambda V(a,b,h)$$

There is now an extra parameter $\lambda$ called the Lagrange multiplier.

[1]: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#:~:text=In%20mathematical%20optimization%2C%20the%20method,chosen%20values%20of%20the%20variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#:%7E:text=In%20mathematical%20optimization%2C%20the%20method,chosen%20values%20of%20the%20variables)).

Comment: I tried this and the derivation felt nice, but I got stuck with two (expectedly) symmetric equations, looking as unsolvable as before: https://i.imgur.com/OhKNTmJ.png

Answer (score 3):

I would agree that Lagrange multipliers would be my approach to solving this problem. But to move forward with what you have, what you could do is first work at a fixed height and show that the aspect ratio that minimizes surface area with both volume and height fixed is $r=1$.

With volume $V$ and height $h$, your surface area is $$A(a,b)=C+a(a^2+D)^{1/2}+b(b^2+D)^{1/2},$$ where $C$ is a constant and $D$ is a strictly positive constant. One ''nice'' thing about this approach is that, for a fixed height, the first term in the surface area (the area of the base) becomes a constant.

We also calculate that, for a fixed height and volume, $$\frac{db}{da}=-\frac{b}{a}.$$ We calculate $$\frac{dA}{da} = \Bigl[\frac{2a^2+D}{\sqrt{a^2+D}}\Bigr]-\frac{b}{a}\Bigl[\frac{2b^2+D}{\sqrt{b^2+D}}\Bigr].$$ Setting equal to zero, moving the subtracted term to the other side of the equation, and multiplying through by $a$ gives $$\frac{2a^3+Da}{\sqrt{a^2+D}}=\frac{2b^3+Db}{\sqrt{b^2+D}}. $$ If we define $$f(x) = \frac{2x^3+Dx}{\sqrt{a^2+D}},$$ we see that the previous equation is $f(a)=f(b)$. If $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$ (which I believe it is because I plotted it with a sample value of $D$, and I'm an optimist), then it must be the case that only $a=b$ can solve this equality. But since $f$ is non-negative, in order to show that it is strictly increasing, it is enough to show that $f^2$ is strictly increasing.

You can use calculus to show that $f^2$ is strictly increasing, which is probably what you want to do if you're teaching yourself calculus, but there's also a trick you can use here. Take $\vartheta>1$ and note that $$f(\vartheta x)^2 = \frac{4(\vartheta x)^6 + 4D(\vartheta x)^4 + D^2(\vartheta x)^2}{(\vartheta x)^2+D}.$$ Note that the numerator increased by a factor of **more than** $\vartheta^2$, since each term has a factor of at least $\vartheta^2$, and every term is non-negative. The denominator increased by a factor of **less than** $\vartheta^2$, since one term in the denominator increased by that factor and the other did not increase at all. This shows that $f$ is strictly increasing and the only critical point for the surface area at a fixed height is with $a=b$ (or $r=1$).  It still remains to show that this is a minimum surface area at the fixed height. But this is pretty easy by considering the fact that as $a\to\infty$, the surface area at a fixed height goes to $\infty$, since it has an $a\sqrt{a^2+h^2}$ and other non-negative terms. Same for $b$. So on either side of our critical point, we have larger surface area values.

This removes the aspect ratio from the problem and allows us to consider only square base pyramids. From here we have two variables, $a$ and $h$, and one constraint, $a^2h=3V$.